# Converting SKSpriteNode into SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working in  Swift 3.1. I want to create a shadow for a SKSpriteNode. I'm thinking of doing a SKShapeNode from my SKSpriteNode and giving it some glow and alpha.

But how can I convert SKSpriteNode into SKShapeNode?

Comment: What kind of shadow effect do you plan on doing?  A circle blob or a reflection of the actual sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plan is to make a shadow that looks like your sprite, then using another SpriteNode instead would be advisable.  `SKShapeNodes` have poor performance and the process of converting the sprite into a vector shape will be processing heavy.

You should have read about [SKEffectNode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skeffectnode) because you could use them to create a SpriteNode with your current texture and apply some effects on it to turn your texture black, blured ans maybe even use affine transformation to distort and rotate the texture so it looks like a shadow.

To make things more GPU/CPU efficient in the case where you have many shadows, you could simply put all the shadow sprites as child of a single SKEffectNode that will apply the effects on every shadow sprite all at once.  I assume that positionning the shadow under the main sprite would not be a challenge for you.
Having the shadow as a child of the main sprite would force you to put an effect node for every sprite casting a shadow, and would cause the effects to be processed over and over.  By putting every shadow as a child of the same node, they will get rendered all at once and the effect will be processed only once every frame.

I hope it helps!

Comment: If you are into it, you can also use SKShaders to do the job, but it implies writing GLSL code.  I've tried working with those and the implementation in xCode is kinda weird.  Also debugging GLSL is really hard and not convenient at the current state of development.  It's also poorly documented (not GLSL, but Apple's integration in SpriteKit).  Maybe it will get better with Metal taking more and more room out there.

Answer (score 0):

`SKShapeNode`'s are known to have poor performance in SpriteKit. Instead, you should add another `SKSpriteNode` for the shadow, and add it as a child to the main `SKSpriteNode`.

If you want the shadow to appear below its parent, you may have to adjust it's relative z-position as well.